# android layout with dynamic content?

Tags: android

hi sorry i searched but didnt find the best answer i could use :( 
here is the description:
i have an android project in which there are 55 activities with 55 layouts .(each activity has a layout) .
many of these activities have same style , i mean only their contents change (for example one of them has a picture of a fish and another one has picture of a lion and so on)

**Edit:** i have included the picture for what the matter to be more exact about what i want to do:

http://i45.tinypic.com/biqmv8.png

so here is the question:

how can i create this app with less xml layouts? is there a way to have dynamic contents? if so could you please help me or show me the required tutorial to achieve this end? 
thanks.

Comment: Where are the images stored ? Cloud or resources ?

Comment: hi they are stored at resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a generic layout dynamically filled by a generic Activity receiving the image URL or resourceId in parameter

Comment: thanks for the answer,could you explain a little more how to do this? or is there a reference or example ?

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout fr = new FrameLayout(this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable);
    fr.addView(iv);
    setContentView(fr);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but doesnt this have only 1 image?could you explain a little more? thanks you

Comment: probably this may help you.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

and this one too:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Comment: thanks i take a look.i guess for my case i have to use sqlite db .